# Protocol type cannot conform to protocol because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, codable, decodable

Within the app, we have two types of Stickers, String and Bitmap. Each sticker pack could contain both types. This is how I declare the models:

```
// Mark: - Models

protocol Sticker: Codable {
}

public struct StickerString: Sticker,  Codable, Equatable {
    let fontName: String
    let character: String
}

public struct StickerBitmap: Sticker,  Codable, Equatable {
    let imageName: String
}
```

After the user chooses some stickers and used them, we want to save the stickers into `UserDefaults` so we can show him the "Recently Used" Sticker tab. I'm trying to Decode the saved `[Sticker]` array:

```
let recentStickers = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Sticker].self, from: data)
```

But I get the following compile error:

```
Protocol type 'Sticker' cannot conform to 'Decodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
```

I can't understand why as I declared `Sticker` as `Codable` which also implement `Decodable`. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong: A protocol cannot conform to a protocol. The first parameter of `decode` must be a concrete type. A solution is to use a generic type constrained to `Codable`.

Comment: @vadian Hey Vadian! Thank you for your reply. Might be a lack of my English skills. I can't understand what 'concrete type' means. I'll try to come up with a generic type solution like you wrote

Comment: Your code contains two concrete types, `StickerString` and `StickerBitmap`.

Comment: @vadian I added `associatedtype` Inside `Sticker` and within `StickerString` and `StickerBitmap` I'm assigning their own types in the `typealias`, but it gives me the same error. Will I be able to declare a `[Sticker]` array or It'll have to be either one of the concrete types?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rather than protocols use generics.

Declare a simple function

```
func decodeStickers<T : Decodable>(from data : Data) throws -> T
{
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

`T` can be a single object as well as an array.

---

In your structs drop the `Sticker` protocol. You can also delete `Equatable` because it's getting synthesized in structs.

```
public struct StickerString : Codable {
    let fontName: String
    let character: String
}

public struct StickerBitmap : Codable {
    let imageName: String
}
```

---

To decode one of the sticker types annotate the type

```
let imageStickers = """
[{"imageName":"Foo"},{"imageName":"Bar"}]
"""    
let stickerData = Data(imageStickers.utf8)

let recentStickers : [StickerBitmap] = try! decodeStickers(from: stickerData)
print(recentStickers.first?.imageName)
```

and

```
let stringSticker = """
{"fontName":"Times","character":""}
"""    
let stickerData = Data(stringSticker.utf8)

let sticker : StickerString = try! decodeStickers(from: stickerData)
print(sticker.character)
```

---

To decode an array of `StickerString` and `StickerBitmap` types declare a wrapper enum with associated values

```
enum Sticker: Codable {

    case string(StickerString)
    case image(StickerBitmap)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let stringData = try container.decode(StickerString.self)
            self = .string(stringData)
        } catch DecodingError.keyNotFound {
            let imageData = try container.decode(StickerBitmap.self)
            self = .image(imageData)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
            case .string(let string) : try container.encode(string)
            case .image(let image) : try container.encode(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can decode

```
let stickers = """
[{"imageName":"Foo"},{"imageName":"Bar"}, {"fontName":"Times","character":""}]
"""

let stickerData = Data(stickers.utf8)
let recentStickers = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Sticker].self, from: stickerData)
print(recentStickers)
```

In a table view just `switch` on the enum

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sticker = stickers[indexPath.row]
    switch sticker {
    case .string(let stringSticker): 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withCellIdentifier: "StringStickerCell", for: indexPath) as! StringStickerCell
        // update UI
        return cell
    case .image(let imageSticker): 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withCellIdentifier: "ImageStickerCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageStickerCell
        // update UI
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Vadian! Thank you for the detailed response. The question is if it's possible to combine both 'StickerString' and 'StickerBitmap' in the same array?

Comment: From what I understood from your answer, we could use generics to decode/code my data. But I'm trying to understand something: Eventually, when we are decoding the data back into Stickers, I need to have the option to use both types of stickers in the same array, as the user can choose stickers from multiple sticker packs. If we don't have a relation between the two stickers types, how can we achieve this?

Comment: Cool! It's compiling:)! The only thing I'm struggling with is that if we have an array [Sticker] and I want to get the associated value from the enum (when displaying the recent Stickers I'm using the [Sticker] array as the data source, and depends on the data type I'm showing a different cell). How would I achieve this? As both types don't have anything in common so I can't return a shared type

Comment: The array must look like `[.string(StickerString()), .image(StickerBitmap())]`. In `cellForRow` switch on the enum like in the `encode` method.

Comment: WORKS!!!! Awesome! Wow, I thought it'll be so much simpler when I started, seems to be quiet trivial. I have to know: Do you think there was a better way to approach it? Has it took much more energy than I expected, was basically just a combination of two data-types.

Comment: In conjunction with `Codable` it's the most efficient way. Without `Codable` the simpler protocol solution as common type is sufficient

Comment: instead of `DecodingError.keyNotFound` should be `DecodingError.typeMismatch`

Answer (score 1):

what happens here is kind of self explanatory

```
JSONDecoder().decode(/* swift here is expecting class or struct that conforms to Codable */.self, from: data)
```

but let us assume that you can pass a protocol
in your protocol

```
protocol Sticker: Codable {
}
```

where is the properties that you are expecting swift to decode from data ?

you added the properties in

```
public struct StickerString: Sticker,  Codable, Equatable { // it should have redundendant conformance as well as you are conforming to Coddle again
    let fontName: String // here is the properties you are expected to be decoded with the coding keys
    let character: String // here is the properties you are expected to be decoded with the coding keys
}
```

Here is what I suggest you do as long you want the type you want to decode to be dynamic

```
class GenericService< /* here you can pass your class or struct that conforms to Codable */ GenericResponseModel: Codable> {

func buildObjectFromResponse(data: Data?) -> GenericResponseModel? {
        var object : GenericResponseModel?
        do {
            object = try JSONDecoder().decode(GenericResponseModel.self , from: data!)
        } catch (let error){
            print(error)
        }
        return object
    }

}
```

- through this class you can pass any type or even list that conforms to Codable
- then you will decouple the type checking from the decoding process using the method below

```
private func handleDecodingTypes (stickers: [Sticker]){
        for sticker in stickers {
            if sticker is StickerString {
                /* do the decoding here */
            }
            if sticker is StickerBitmap {
                /* do the decoding here */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Karem! Thank you for your answer. From what I understood from your answer and Vadian one, we could use generics to decode/code my data. But I'm trying to understand something: Eventually, when we are decoding the data back into Stickers, I need to have the option to use both *types of stickers* in the same array, as the user can choose stickers from multiple sticker packs. If we don't have a relation between the two stickers types, how can we achieve this?

Comment: I've edited the answer and the main goal for me was to decouple the process of casting the object to a specific concrete type and the decoding process as the decoding process should not be aware of the contents it decodes

Answer (score 0):

The Sticker protocol is not confirming/implementing the Codable, it is actually inheriting from the Codable. As the error message suggests, Protocols do not conform to other protocols only concrete types do.

```
protocol Sticker: Codable //This is Protocol inheritance
```

By stating

```
public struct StickerString: Sticker
```

Means that Sticker string conforms to Sticker and the Sticker is child of Codable, so StickerString eventually conforms to Codable. There is no need to state conformance again i.e:

```
public struct StickerString: Sticker,  Codable //Conformance to Codable is redundant
```

Now coming to the decoding part.

```
  let recentStickers = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Sticker].self, from: data)
```

The decode method needs a concrete type. It doesn't have any information about the underlying type or its attributes because Sticker is just a protocol itself inheriting from Codable that has no properties/attributes.
Compiler would not have any problem combining both the StrickerString and StickerBitmap after they've decoded e.g.

```
let stickerString = try JSONDecoder().decode(StickerString.self, from: data)
let stickerBitmap = try JSONDecoder().decode(StickerBitmap.self, from: data)
let stickers : [Sticker] = [stickerString, stickerBitmap]
```